# How do I delete iTunes from my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, itunes

I no longer need iTunes on my MacBook Pro and want to remove both the application and the music stored locally.

How can I accomplish this on macOS 10.12 Sierra?

Comment: What version of **OS X/macOS** are you running? Do you want to just delete the application or the music, etc. too.

Comment: Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6. I want to delete the application and the music too

Answer (score 2):

**To delete iTunes Music:**

Your iTunes Music is stored in a Music Library. The default location is in the Music Folder in Finder.

If you don't know where the Music folder is, open Finder and click Go > Home and open the folder Music.

You can delete this entire folder. It will offer to create a new blank Library next time you open iTunes. You will lose all the music, of course, when you delete this folder.

**Music/iTunes Application**

On macOS Sierra you *can* delete iTunes, but I'd recommend against it. You would likely have to disable security features. Remember that Music is just a few hundred megabytes - less than 0.08% of even the smallest hard drives.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> I want to delete the application and the music too

Understand that updates to **macOS Sierra** can/may restore the **iTunes.app**, in which case you'd have to perform some of the following steps again. Upgrading **macOS** will install **iTunes.app**, or **Music.app**, depending on the version you upgrade to.

**Note:** Make sure you have a current backup of the media you have in **iTunes** before you delete your music, etc.

Please read and understand these steps before proceeding.

1. **System Preferences** > **User & Groups** > **You** > **Login Items**, fo **iTunesHelper** exists, then **Click the lock to make changes.**, entries your **Admin** credentials, select **iTunesHelper**, then click the **[-]** button.
2. If **iTunes** is closed and it shows on the **Dock** then *control-click* (*right-click*) it and select: **Options** > **Remove from Dock**
3. Open **Terminal** and use the following *compound command* to reboot to **Recovery Mode**:

   ```
    sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"; sleep 2; sudo reboot
   ```

- Assuming you are an **Admin** account, type in your password and press: <kbd>enter</kbd>

4. Once in **Recovery Mode** from the **macOS Utilities** menu, click **Utilities** > **Terminal** and run the following commands, which assumes that **Macintosh HD** is the name of your **Startup Disk**:

   ```
    cd '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications'
    rm -r iTunes.app
    reboot
   ```
5. One back to your normal **Desktop**, to remove the media content of **iTunes**, your music etc. that existed in **iTunes**, open **Finder** and navigate to the **Music** *folder* in you **Home** *folder* and *control-click* (*right-click*) on the **iTunes** *folder* and select **Move to Trash**, then empty the **Trash**. On the **Dock** *control-click* (*right-click*) on the **Trash** can and click **Empty Trash**.

Comment: Does Sierra really require recovery mode to delete standard applications?

Comment: @nohillside, RE: "Does Sierra really require recovery mode to delete standard applications? " --  In **macOS Sierra** the default _applications_ are owned by `root:wheel`, have _extended attributes_ `com.apple.rootless` and are `restricted` with **ACL**s `group:everyone deny delete`, so yes, one either can boot to **Recovery Mode** and delete the target _application_ right there and be done with it, or do the whole boot to **Recovery Mode**, disable **SIP**, reboot to normal mode remove the **ACL**s, delete the target _app_, reboot to **Recovery Mode**, enable **SIP**, reboot to normal mode.